# Как игнорировать ошибки addEventListener, если странице нет элемента?

Tags: javascript

Есть 1 общий **file.js** , где написаны функции для всего сайта. 
Если на 1 странице есть кнопка то **file.js** работает нормально, а на второй странице этой кнопки может не быть, и `addEventListener` выдает ошибку, что элемент `null` и **file.js** перестает работать.

На текущий момент обход- все оборачивать в if.

```
if(el) {
   el.addEventListener('click', () => alert(1))
}
```

Есть более лаконичные способы промолчать об отсутствии элемента?

Или единственный вариант - вообще все подряд оборачивать в `if`?  Что сильно увеличит количество кода.

Ошибка `addEventListener`, если элемента нет:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at

Comment: Можно обработать это исключение 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: @ВладленВожжаев лучше уж `if` использовать, чем в `try...catch` всё оборачивать.

Comment: `el && el.addEventListener('click', handlerClick);`.Но, как мне кажется, идеальным будет один обработчик кликов на весь скрипт.

Comment: а зачем подключать `file.js` туда, где его не к чему применить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, проще написать метод и туда передавать элемент, на который нужно listener навесить.

```
function setEventListener(el, f) {
    if(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', f)
    }
}
```

А в коде везде вызывать:

```
setEventListener(el, () => alert(1));
```

Тогда проверка всего в одном месте будет.

Comment: `() => f()` -> `f`

Comment: @Grundy верное замечание )

Comment: Невероятно интересное решение!